# What is the meaning of "he was there"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "he was there" in this sentence?

> It had taken him a while to talk himself out of his compunctions about this shocking notion, but by the mid-1950 **he was there**.

Comment: He had [at last] found it possible to accept that the notion was true. To 'get there' or 'be there' is often used metaphorically in the same way as 'catch on' or 'crack it'. 'Come to understand / realise'. "So, not all pre-modifiers are adjectives: 'football' in 'football manager' is an attributive noun. So is 'gas' in 'gas fire'. And 'school' in 'school dinners'....  Are you there yet? (Have you got it / the point yet?)"

Comment: So nice. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably visualizing his attitude (with or without compunctions about the shocking notion) as a location, and saying by mid-1950, his attitude was now in a place where he had no compunctions about the shocking notion.